# count the numbers of differences in each columns with data reference impossible?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I need to count the sum of the differences between a set of known data. The equivalent in php is 
`(count(array_diff_assoc($array1))`. Is this possible with Mysql? I have a set of data to compare with each others field column in the table.

my data to compare is `columnA : 3, columnB : 6, columnC : 4`

the test table is :

```
   ID       columnA     columnB    columnC
   1           2           6         1
   2           6           1         3
   3           3           6         4
```

result expected :

```
 ID     numbersofdifferences
  3            0
  1            2
  2            3
```

thanks for any help,
Jesisca

Comment: wouldn't you need to compare two tables with array_diff_assoc in PHP? And in that case, this wouldn't work with what you're describing as your output because the tables are of vastly different sizes?

Comment: more details, i need to addition differents values to this result , do you know how i can make the sum of STYLE + PROF + TotalDiff ?! . i have this : SELECT    
something,   abs( 100-10 ) as STYLE  ,  abs(20-80) as PROF, (case when `prof_extend`.b = 1 then 0 else 1 end) +
    (case when `prof_extend`.c = 1 then 0 else 1 end) +
(case when `prof_extend`.d = 5 then 0 else 1 end) +
(case when `prof_extend`.e = 1 then 0 else 1 end) +
(case when `prof_extend`.v = 3 then 0 else 1 end) +
    (case when `prof_extend`.w = 4 then 0 else 1 end) TotalDiff

Comment: @jess If you have another question then you should Ask a new one, don't update this one with new requirements.

Comment: @jess Your "more details" comment make this another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily the cleanest but you could use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select id,
    sum(case when columna = 3 then 0 else 1 end) +
    sum(case when columnb = 6 then 0 else 1 end) +
    sum(case when columnc = 4 then 0 else 1 end) TotalDiff
from yourtable
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84a53/4).

Edit, this could be done without the aggregate function as well:

```
select id,
    (case when columna = 3 then 0 else 1 end) +
    (case when columnb = 6 then 0 else 1 end) +
    (case when columnc = 4 then 0 else 1 end) TotalDiff
from yourtable;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84a53/10)

Comment: heh, I did mine exactly the same way.

Comment: except, I don't think you need the aggregate functions.

Comment: @McKay You're right I added a version without the aggregate. Using the aggregate will allow for values across multiple rows. The OP didn't specify if the `id` would be unique.

Comment: yeah, if he needs to aggregate across ids, then the sum would be necessary. It's hard to determine quite what the OP wants because the PHP function doesn't do what he's asking precisely.

Comment: Many thanks both for your help, it seems to work fine ! I have 25 fields to compare :) , so i hope this way dosn't consume to much ressource ..?! I have not enought reputation for voting ur answer :(

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a function built in to do something like that, but you could do it manually.

```
select
    id,
    case columnA when $columnA then 1 else 0 end +
      case columnB when $columnB then 1 else 0 end +
      case columnC when $columnC then 1 else 0 end differences
  from
    myTable
```

But if you want them in order, you'll want a subselect

```
select * from 
  (
    select
        id,
        case columnA when $columnA then 1 else 0 end +
          case columnB when $columnB then 1 else 0 end +
          case columnC when $columnC then 1 else 0 end differences
      from
        myTable
  ) sqlRequiresNameHere
  order by differences
```